# Maintain uniform axis limits in all three subplots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure, subplot

Following is the code I've written which involves a `subplot` command inside a for loop. I want each `subplot` to have the same y-axis limits, say 0 to 15. But the three plots have different (adjusted) y-axis limits which defeats the very purpose of comparing the three plots. How do I maintain same ylimits in all three subplots?

```
w = -pi:0.001:pi;
N = [8 10 14];

for i = 1:3
    subplot(3, 1, i);
    W = exp(-1i*w*(N(i)-1)/2).*sin(w*N(i)/2)./sin(w/2);
    plot(w, abs(W));
    xlabel('\omega'); ylabel('Magnitude');
    title(sprintf('N = %d', N(i)));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`linkaxes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html) for that:

```
w = -pi:0.001:pi;
N = [8 10 14];

ax = NaN(1,3); % preallocate
for i = 1:3
    subplot(3, 1, i);
    ax(i) = gca; % take note of axis handle
    W = exp(-1i*w*(N(i)-1)/2).*sin(w*N(i)/2)./sin(w/2);
    plot(w, abs(W));
    xlabel('\omega'); ylabel('Magnitude');
    title(sprintf('N = %d', N(i)));
end
linkaxes(ax) % link axis limits
```

---

As an alternative, you can set the axis limits manually to the maximum size required by all subplots:

```
w = -pi:0.001:pi;
N = [8 10 14];

ax_size = NaN(3,4); % preallocate
for i = 1:3
    subplot(3, 1, i);
    W = exp(-1i*w*(N(i)-1)/2).*sin(w*N(i)/2)./sin(w/2);
    plot(w, abs(W));
    ax_size(i,:) = axis; % take note of axis size
    xlabel('\omega'); ylabel('Magnitude');
    title(sprintf('N = %d', N(i)));
end
ax_target = [min(ax_size(:,1),[],1) max(ax_size(:,2),[],1) ...
     min(ax_size(:,3),[],1) max(ax_size(:,4),[],1)]; % compute target size
for ii = 1:3
    subplot(3, 1, ii);
    axis(ax_target) % set target size
end
```

Comment: Ok, so I made the same edit to my code and ran it. It happens that the maximum value of the y-axis ends well below the maximum value of one of the subplots, causing it to cutoff small portion of the graph. How do I make sure all the subplots are accommodated properly well within the respective subplot figures?

Comment: @MaxFrost I0m not sure what you mean. In the example in my code (taken from yours) the y-axis limits were originally 10, 10, 20, and with `linkaxes` they become 20, 20, 20. Is that not what you want?

Comment: They remain at 10, 10, 10 in my case. Any idea why this difference? I copy-pasted the code from your answer and I still end up with 10, 10, 10.

Comment: @MaxFrost Perhaps the behaviour is version-dependent. I'm using R2017b. You may need to set the axis size manually to the max and min of the individual subplots; see second part of edited answer